# Log not initiated when running app in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j, slf4j

When I run my application using the Maven-generated packages, the logs appear fine as per the `log4j.xml`.  The `log4j.xml` file is located in the same location where the `pom.xml` is so I think the build picks it up and locates it properly for the runtime.

However, sometimes I like to run the app out of the IDE for debugging (`IntelliJ IDEA`) and the IDE picks up the Maven config seamlessly without any additional tweaking. One problem is that it never logs anything nor does it throw any exceptions upon `logger.info("...")` and such.

Can you take a guess what I can do to keep log writes on when in the debug mode?  Below is the log4j.xml.  I tried changing the `fileName` attribute to a fully qualified path but it didn't work.  E.g. is it possible to ask the `Logger` into which physical file it is writing entries?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="File" fileName="my_app_logs">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-6p]:[%d{ISO8601}]:[%t]:[%c{2}]:%m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="debug"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the log4j.xml file in src/main/resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would have suggested the same answer.
Have you checked if the file "my_app_logs" is not created in a different directory than the one created when launching the test from maven
You should check in the working directory of the test, from the run configuration of idea.

To validate that the log4.xml is actually loaded, you could had a console appender and assigned it to root. Then if the file is find by log4j, you'll see the output in IDEA console.